# Azure kudu vfs API does not support files names having "# " in them

Tags: azure, powershell, vfs, kudu

I am using kudu vfs API to sync two folders between two azure websites. For this I am downloading files from 1st website which are not in 2nd website and uploading them to 2nd website.

Download file:

```
 Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $kuduApiUrl `
                    -Headers @{"Authorization"=$kuduApiAuthorisationToken;"If-Match"="*"} `
                    -Method GET `
                    -OutFile $localPath `
                    -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Upload File:

```
 $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $kuduApiUrl `
                    -Headers @{"Authorization"=$kuduApiAuthorisationToken;"If-Match"="*"} `
                    -Method PUT `
                    -InFile $localPath `
                    -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Everything works if file name does not contains `#` in it. Failed cases: 
`$kuduApiUrl = "https://targetWebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/Content/Uploads/09.01#Import Listabc.txt"`

`$kuduApiUrl = "https://targetWebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/Content/Uploads/#09.01Import Listabc.txt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `#` is the escape character in URI, just replace the `#` with `%23`, it will work fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes it downloads the file but with name `09.01%23Import Listabc.txt` instead of original name, but what good news is that when upload same file then it automatically changes the name to `09.01#Import Listabc.txt` in Kudu which resolve my problem.